# Disable IPv6 in QEmu

Tags: ipv6, qemu

Is there a way to stop QEmu from providing IPv6 connectivity to the guest by giving command line options to `qemu-system-*` while still keeping IPv4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With user-mode NAT, you can selectively enable IPv4 and IPv6 in any combination. The default is probably to have both, so you’ll have to explicitly tell QEMU to do otherwise:

```
-netdev user,id=str[,ipv4[=on|off]][,net=addr[/mask]][,host=addr]
         [,ipv6[=on|off]][,ipv6-net=addr[/int]][,ipv6-host=addr]
         [,restrict=on|off][,hostname=host][,dhcpstart=addr]
```

So basically just pass `-netdev user,id=whatever,ipv6=off` and you should be good.

If you do not use user-mode NAT, you’ll have to use IPTables or the like to prevent the guest from achieving IPv6 connectivity.

Comment: Thanks - this gets at the core of the issue! `ipv6=off` is the key. However, if you specify any custom network options to QEmu it no longer makes you the default emulated NIC; you need to make one yourself. E.g. `-netdev user,id=user0,ipv6=off -device virtio-net,netdev=user0`

Answer (score 1):

`Qemu` is virtual hardware - so on this level there is no concept of `IPv4`, `IPv6` etc., it is just a NIC. The analogon would be to ask, if it is possible to configure an intel or Broadcom NIC on the hardware level to disallow `IPv6`.

What you can do is to create firewall rules on the host, that stops `IPv6` packet sfrom reaching or leaving the vbridge that qemu connects to, but be aware that this has nothing to do with `Qemu` itself.

Comment: By default, QEmu uses a virtual network with an emulated NIC: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Network_backend_types

Comment: @Lassi - that's exactly what I said. Whatever backend you use, it is not **protocol** based, but **packet** based, so there is no dstinction between `IPv4` and `IPv6` at that layer

Comment: QEmu's default user-mode network stack does not pass the ethernet frames from the emulated NIC verbatim to the host NIC. Instead, it extracts the IP packets from the guest's ethernet frames and passes them to the host's IP stack (not directly to host ethernet). And vice versa - host IP packets are placed into artificial ethernet frames which then go to the emulated guest NIC. See @Daniel B's answer.

Comment: If **user** mode networking is good enough for you, then you might even consider dropping it alltogether and just using sockets.